# Simple canvas in angularjs directive

Tags: angularjs, html5-canvas

I'm stuck (probably on some dumb mistake) trying to make a directive work with a canvas.

When I execute my code I get an `element.getContext is not a function`which seems weird as my element is actually an HTMLCanvasElement.

This is my directive

```
.directive('pitchCanvas', function() {

    function link(scope, element, attrs) {
        console.info('element: ' + element);
        var ctx = element.getContext('2d');
        ctx.font = "30px Arial";
        ctx.fillText("Hello World", 10, 50);
    }

  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    scope: true,
    link: link,
    template: '<canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="100" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;"></canvas>'
  };
})
```

and this is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/danaya/3csrqh36/3/) where I placed a simplified version of my code and can´t make work.

Any help will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should replace:

```
element.getContext('2d');
```

With:

```
element[0].getContext('2d');
```

Comment: This is because element is not a node, unlike what you get when you query using native javascript. It is actually a jqLite object(similar to jQuery object). So, like what we do to convert a jquery object into plain javascript object, this also has to be converted to use javascript functions